# IS it possible to send an array of user emails to find user accounts for in AuthZero?

Tags: c#, auth0

I have a large user base, many of whom have AuthZero accounts to login to my system, and I was wondering, is it possible to send AuthZero a collection of user emails to search on rather than doing a search for each user?

For example:

Currently, I'm having to hit AuthZero's endpoint for each user I have -

```
List myUsers = new List<users>(.....nUSers);
foreach(var user in myUSers){
$"/api/v2/users-by-email?fields=email,last_login,logins_count,blocked&include_fields=true&email={user.EmailAddress.Trim().ToLower()}";
}
```

The problem is, this can take a very long time if I have a large group of users I have to search on, which I do.  So my question is, is it possible to send a group of email addresses rather than a single email address?

Comment: You can use `OR` maybe, like `email:("john@exampleco.com" OR "jane@exampleco.com")` https://auth0.com/docs/users/search/v3

Comment: @Hackerman not nothing like email:([john@example.com", "jane@example.com"])?

Comment: Nope....the only method allowed by the api is to use `OR`...,maybe you can try using multiple `OR`s

Comment: I'll give it a shot, thanks.